# How to show another text value insteadof showing of existing from ng-repeat for one property using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I have data:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in demo">
          {{item.text}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.demo=[
                {"id":"ABC", "name":"ABC","text":"ABC"},
                {"id":"PQR","name":"PQR","text":"PQR"},
                {"id":"XYZ","name":"XYZ","text":"XYZ"}
                ];
    }]);
```

I want to display the `output` like below on `html view` page:

- ABC
- PQR
- MNO

instead of showing:

- ABC
- PQR
- XYZ

i.e `ex`: I want to show the text value as: "MNO" instead of "XYZ" on displaying of view page, I don't want to change anything in the variable(`$scope.demoValues`) using `angularjs`. I am not sure how to develop this. Please help me. Thanks.

Created [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/L7esmwoa/4/).

Comment: You want to display a value from an array that doesn't exist?

Comment: `{{ item.text.replace('XYZ', 'MNO') }}` ?

Comment: @ChrisPickford, yes, I want to display value that does not exist, only for display purpose/view purpose.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, I am not sure how I can apply that {{ item.text.replace('XYZ', 'MNO') }} on ng-repeat please ?

Comment: Replace your {{ item.text }} line with it.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, Yes, wow really, it is working. Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking to do a straight text replacement in the view when a particular value is encountered, you could use [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in demo">
    {{ item.text.replace('XYZ', 'MNO') }}
</li>
```